# Access - Tricky SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I have an Access database with contacts, phone numbers, fax, mobile. Example:

```
Table: Numbers

Name       Number      Type
George     555555      Phone
George     656565      Phone
George     323232      Fax
Michael    656565      Phone
John       323232      Fax
Steve      234345      Mobile
```

I want to select the person who has phone number 656565 **AND** fax number 323232,
namely here only George and not Michael or John. (Name is a foreign key if that helps)
What is the SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is set out below, but any answer will, I think, depend on [Name] being a unique key in whatever table it is from:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM Numbers 
WHERE Type = 'Phone' 
AND [Number] = '656565'
AND [Name] IN     
    (SELECT [Name] FROM Numbers 
     WHERE Type = 'Fax' 
     AND [Number] = '323232')
```

I have assumed that Number is a text field because phone numbers generally are stored as text.

Comment: I always do this with a JOIN instead of an IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look up the concept of correlated subqueries.

Comment: I don't see how a correlated subquery would be necessary here at all. Please provide SQL.